# You should/might/ought to consider going

Tags: difference

You should consider going.

You might consider going.

You ought to consider going.

Could someone please explain the difference between these to me?

Comment: Please to do not post open-ended basic questions like this. Questions need to show effort on your part and/or some research by you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without any context I don't know the tone of voice! Are we throwing someone out of a party or recommending an art exhibition? I'll assume it's an art exhibition.

[By the way, we would normally just say, "You should go" or "You ought to go".]

`*You should consider going.*` - This suggests nothing more than "I think you would enjoy it."

`*You ought to consider going.*` - This has a slight implication that it is your *duty* to go: perhaps I think you would profit from going. Or perhaps I think you owe it to the artist to go and see his/her paintings.

`*You might consider going*` - This is used either as a polite suggestion -

> "I went to see it last week. Actually John, **you** might consider
>   going. I think you would enjoy it."

or as a mild entreaty to think about it at least -

> "I'm not going. I don't like his paintings!"
>
> "But he's your brother! You might (at least) **consider** going.")

[*Might* has so many uses. I think it must be a difficult word to learn.]